# Computing densities for discrete data in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, kernel-density, density-plot

I want to plot a density histogram in R with discrete data.
Given that my dataset is very large I need to compute the densities prior plotting.

However, I find that using the `stats::density` function provides different results compared to `..density..` in `ggplot2`. Why is that? Also the ..density.. results from ggplot2 are in line with what is expected whereas stats::density are not.

See reproducible example below.

Many Thanks

```
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)

df <- data.frame(A = round(rnorm(1000)),
           B = round(rnorm(1000)),
           C = round(rnorm(1000))) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = everything(), names_to = "group")

dens_df <- df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarise(dens = list(density(value, from = -3, to = 6, n = length(-3:6)))) %>% #compute density and nest into list
  mutate(density.x = map(dens, ~.x[["x"]]), #extract x values
         density.y = map(dens, ~.x[["y"]])) %>%  #extract y values
  select(-dens) %>% 
  unnest(cols = c(density.x, density.y))

plot_dens <- dens_df %>% 
  ggplot()+
  aes(x = density.x, y = density.y) %>% 
  geom_col()+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(-3,10,1))+
  stat_function(fun = dnorm, n = 10, args = list(mean = 0, sd = 1), geom = "point", col = "red") +
  stat_function(fun = dnorm, n = 10, args = list(mean = 0, sd = 1), geom = "point", size = 2, col = "red") +
  stat_function(fun = dnorm, n = 10, args = list(mean = 0, sd = 1), geom = "line", col = "red") +
  facet_wrap(~group)+
  labs(title = "using stats::density")

plot_geom <- df %>% 
  ggplot()+
  aes(x = value, y = ..density..) %>% 
  geom_histogram(
    binwidth = 1,
    col = "white")+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(-3,10,1))+
  stat_function(fun = dnorm, n = 10, args = list(mean = 0, sd = 1), geom = "point", col = "red") +
  stat_function(fun = dnorm, n = 10, args = list(mean = 0, sd = 1), geom = "point", size = 2, col = "red") +
  stat_function(fun = dnorm, n = 10, args = list(mean = 0, sd = 1), geom = "line", col = "red") +
  facet_wrap(~group)+
  labs(title = "using ggplot2 ..density..")


plot_dens + plot_geom
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is that `stats::density` isn't the correct function to use on discrete data. `stats::density` uses a smoothing kernel and will provide a curve representing the *continuous* density between -3 and 6, even if only sampled at 10 points. This is *not* the same as the densities of discrete data, which is just the frequency of each bin divided by the number of observations. This is what `geom_histogram` is drawing.

The computationally efficient way to get discrete densities is to use `hist` or even just `table(x)/length(x)`.

Here's an example using precomputed densities from `hist`

```r
dens_df <- df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarise(dens = list(hist(value, breaks = seq(-3.5, 6.5), plot = FALSE))) %>% 
  mutate(density.x = map(dens, ~.x[["mids"]]), #extract x values
         density.y = map(dens, ~.x[["density"]])) %>%  #extract y values
  select(-dens) %>% 
  unnest(cols = c(density.x, density.y))
```

We can see this leads to the same plot as `geom_histogram`, using your own plotting code but with the altered `dens_df`

```r
plot_dens <- dens_df %>% 
  ggplot()+
  aes(x = density.x, y = density.y) %>% 
  geom_col()+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(-3,10,1))+
  stat_function(fun = dnorm, n = 10, args = list(mean = 0, sd = 1),
                geom = "point", col = "red") +
  stat_function(fun = dnorm, n = 10, args = list(mean = 0, sd = 1), 
                geom = "point", size = 2, col = "red") +
  stat_function(fun = dnorm, n = 10, args = list(mean = 0, sd = 1), 
                geom = "line", col = "red") +
  facet_wrap(~group)+
  labs(title = "using graphics::hist")

plot_geom <- df %>% 
  ggplot()+
  aes(x = value, y = ..density..) %>% 
  geom_histogram(
    binwidth = 1,
    col = "white")+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(-3,10,1))+
  stat_function(fun = dnorm, n = 10, args = list(mean = 0, sd = 1), 
                geom = "point", col = "red") +
  stat_function(fun = dnorm, n = 10, args = list(mean = 0, sd = 1), 
                geom = "point", size = 2, col = "red") +
  stat_function(fun = dnorm, n = 10, args = list(mean = 0, sd = 1), 
                geom = "line", col = "red") +
  facet_wrap(~group)+
  labs(title = "using ggplot2 ..density..")

plot_dens + plot_geom
```

[image]

Comment: So how come `dnorm` densities match the `hist` frequencies at each discrete x value?

Comment: @CyG because `dnorm` doesn't have spikes at the integer values caused by accumulation of the density kernel. Check the difference between `plot(density(rnorm(1000)))` and `plot(density(round(rnorm(1000))))` and you will see this very clearly.